# White space above and below images using two columns

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats, columns, white-space

So I'm writing an article using the "LaTeX Templates Journal Article", and I seem to have trouble getting my white space above and below figures under control. I have tried redefining the float restrictions, being more and less strict with my float specifiers, using the `\FloatBarrier` package, using `\vspace{-}` before and after the picture, and so much more. I have been through way too many Stack Exchange sites without any solution. This is how it looks at the moment:

[image]

and the code for the picture in question (the right one) is:

```
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width = 1\columnwidth]{Figures/meanScore.png}
    \caption{This figure shows the Mean score for all attributes. Error bars show SD, x-axis shows attributes and y-axis shows mean rating for both repetitions}
    \label{fig:meanScore}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
```

This is not only the problem here. I also see the same annoying white space before a
`\subsection`.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do? I can send the project if needed - I have been using Latex(overleaf) for some time now, but I'm still only on a fundamental level.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You not provide sufficient information about your article (used document class, page layout, used packages ...), so we cant help you. In normal circumstances this should not happen. Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document with some dummy text, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: It looks like TeX spreads the paragraphs because what is currently printed on the next page can't be printed on the current page. Probably, in the line that comes after "Achieving a higher", there is some kind of large footnote or inline math or something else that prevents TeX from putting more lines on the page where the gaps appear.

Comment: I think the question could gain from you providing a complete example. If that is difficult in this case, I think that it would be good to at least show what comes on the next page.

Comment: You've not provided nearly enough information to allow a careful diagnosis of what's going on in your document. Hence, the following suggestions are merely uneducated guesses: (a) You're placing a large float with placement specifier `[H]` on the page that follows the screenshot page, and/or (b) the setting `\flushbottom` is in effect. Do check if inserting the instruction `\raggedbottom` in the preamble makes a difference. And, if you really do use `[H]`, please investigate what happens if you omit that option. Incidentally, a claim such as "I have tried ... so much more" is not actionable.

Comment: looking at your image it looks like you are using `\flushbottom`  so the last baselines align, that means that white space has to stretch just as word spaces stretch to justify paragraphs of text in horizontal justification. So the question is, why doesn't the text at the top of the next pagappear on this page. Or you could use `\raggedbottom` so any excess space came at the bottom.

Comment: Please always show the image _of the code you post_. That is not the case here. You have not provided any code that produces the problem or allows answers to be tested, and the image is of a docuemnt whose code you have not shown.